# Problem with addressing to dynamically created elements in JavaScript (not jquery)

Tags: javascript

I have table in HTML:

And I have button in HTML also.

By clicking on button a new cell appears each time. Every new cell has class of course.
Then I want to click on cell so that new div appears.

It should work like this:

```
cell_1 (class xxx) can create div1
cell_2 (class xxx) can create div2
etc.
```

The problem is: I cannot address to class xxx of these cells correctly.
I have tried to solve it by adding new script in the end of the addEventListener code like this:

```
let popupScript = document.createElement ("script");
    popupScript.src = "newscript.js";
    document.body.appendChild(popupScript);
```

And in this newscript I can address to dynamically created class xxx. But the problem remains: if I create 5 cells and then click on the cell №1, it works like I click 5 times on cell №1.

Also I have tried to use MutationObserver. But the problem remains.

Then I decided to check it another way:
In HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="textClass">1</td>
        <td class="textClass">2</td>
        <td class="textClass">3</td>
        <td class="textClass">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="click_button">GO CLICK</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In JavaScript:

```
for (let g=0; g<4; ++g) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".textClass")[g].addEventListener ("click", function() {console.log (g)});
}
```

Now g in console show the correct number of clicking. One click - one number.

But if I put this code in JavaScript:

```
let x = 0;
document.getElementById ("click_button").addEventListener ("click", function() {
    let y = document.createElement ("div");
    document.body.appendChild (y);
    x++;
});

let observer = new MutationObserver (function () {
for (let g=0; g<x; ++g) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".textClass")[g].addEventListener ("click", function() {console.log (g)});
}
});
observer.observe (document.body, {childList: true});
```

the problem remains. And if you click 4 times on "GO CLICK" and then click on 1st cell, in console you will see (4)0.

So, what is wrong?

Comment: Hard to follow what your asking. What does "I cannot address to class xxx of these cells correctly" mean?

Comment: Every time that you add an element, the callback in the mutation observer will run. This means that a new event listener will be added for each `.textClass` element. Instead, add a single event listener to the `<table>` element and handle your clicks from there. The information about what element is clicked can be found in the `Event` object.

Comment: Keep in mind: `addEventListener()` will *add* event listeners on top of each other. So calling it will not overwrite, but actually add another function to perform on, for example, a click.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, much thanks! You helped me a lot! Now it works well.